# iOS - Segues and Static Cells

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have a group of Static Cells inside a TableView, And I have 3 of these cells (A, B, C) all set up with segues which `push` the Same ViewController onto the screen; This works fine!

What i want is a way for the View controller to identify which cell was clicked: through which the ViewController could alter what it presents. Specifically, I'd like an int (for say) in my viewController to be set to a particular value according to which cell was clicked

I'm guessing I'm missing something in the 
`- (void) prepareForSegue method` ?

Any help is very appreciated

The following Code is in My View Controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
 if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segue1"]){
    selectedSegue = 1;
 } else {
    selectedSegue = 2;
 }

  NSLog(@"Selected Segue: %d", selectedSegue); 
}
```

selectedSegue always returns 0;

I've set the Segue identifier in my storyboard as well

Comment: What is the problem? `-prepareForSegue` should get called each time one of your table cells is tapped. You should just check the segues `identifier` and do the work for each segue.

Comment: My `prepareforSegue` method just never gets called . . . . - I've also edited my question to add detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are almost there. Check the following example implementation of `prepareForSegue:sender:` (**this method signature might even be the problem!**)

```
#pragma mark - Storyboard Methods

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueOne"]) {

        BBFirstViewController *vcOne = (BBFirstViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
        vcOne.someProperty = @1;
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueOne"]) {

        BBSecondViewController *vcTwo = (BBSecondViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
       vcTwo.someProperty = @2;
   }
}
```

Then just make sure in the storyboard file each segue has its `identifier` set:

[image: Xcode Storyboard]

Click on the segue line in between the two view controllers and sets the identifier in the *Attributes Inspector*.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the detailed explanation: If I'm implementing my Static Cells in a `MenuViewController` - The `MenuViewController` *MUST subclass the `ViewController` to which the cells segue will `push` : MoreOver, the `-prepareForSegue` Method must be invoked before in the `MenuViewController` class and not in the `ViewController` class which is pushed - would you please re-inforce this ?